# Symfony2 Twig theming from database?

Tags: symfony, twig

How can add support for theming with Symfony2, where themes (path to the current theme) are stored in database per-user? Example:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| User              | id | username | password | theme_name |
-------------------------------------------------------------
  Bob                 1    Bob        327n829    /Default
  Alice               2    Alice      2c839n42   /Pink
```

So, for a given user, Symfony has to load the correct template from `Resources/views/{theme_name}` and fallback to `Resources/views/Default` if template does not exists.

I've checked these two bundles:

- [LaKrue  / TwigstringBundle](https://github.com/LaKrue/TwigstringBundle) that loads Twig templates from strings
- [liip  / LiipThemeBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle) that allows to define themes in YAML config file

But both seems not fitting my needs. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

We use LiipThemeBundle and our kernel listener:

```
public function onEarlyKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if ($request->attributes->has('_theme') === false) {
        // if you use annotation with doctrine, you'll need to register them before that line
        $user = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findBy(...);

       // you probably will want to set _theme in request context, not in the $request object
        $request->attributes->set('_theme', $user->getTheme());
        $this->container->get('liip_theme.active_theme')->setName($user->getTheme());
    }
    //$this->router->setContext($context);
}
```

There's is [one problem](https://github.com/liip/LiipThemeBundle/issues/25) with LiipThemeBundle that you need to take in account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i really don't need to use a bundle just for changing a path! May i ask why you're changing the active theme in RouteListener? EDIT: that is no need to switch the theme passing theme parameter.

Comment: @Gremo LiipThemeBundle is a way to add theming support  into your project. That  is for "Symfony has to load the correct template from Resources/views/{theme_name} and fallback to Resources/views/Default if template does not exists.". And it's not RouteListener, It's EarlyKernelRequest listener. "that is no need to switch the theme passing theme parameter" what do you mean?

Comment: @Gremo - Did you ever get this working I am having the same problem?